# relative and absolute; responsive center positioning? bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm creating an image gallery with bootstrap and would like to have text show on the center of the images on hover over. So both horizontally and vertically positioned 50% of the image(so it is responsive). At the moment I'm just trying to get the text to display on top of the image correctly but seem to be having problems.

Here is the code I am using: `

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb text-center">
     <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="images/girl.jpg" alt="">
         <h2> Text </h2>
     </a>
 </div>`
```

So I have tried giving the div, a and img elements positioning of 'relative' and then giving h2 positioning of absolute, top and left 50% however it seems to not center it at all and is positioned near to the bottom right corner of the image.

Question is am I doing something wrong that jumps out to anyone? If not I can upload the web files and provide a link to show how it is not working or is there actually an easier or alternative method to achieve this?

Comment: So the `position: absolute` will work, it will but the reference point of the h2 at the center, but the h2 might have interfering styles (margin/padding) so make sure to remove that. Also the h2 will be using it's top/left reference point at 50% (the center). Typically people put a 50% negative margin on the centered element.

Comment: it's invalid to insert `h2` element inside `a` element

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a MDN states anchors can contain flow content, which an h2 is flow content.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All you should need is the following:

```
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.thumbnail h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

`.thumbnail` will stretch to contain the image and the `<h2>` will be centered vertically and horizontally within it.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! Without  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); it was not positioned in the center. Simplying adding the transform line fixed it! Thank you

Comment: man, this solution works so dynamic. even without 100% width it works fine thou.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap classes `position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle` inside a `.position-relative` element.

It basically uses the same rules as [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3979906/jacob)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31144138/17684809) but with Bootstrap classes.

```css
.position-relative {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.position-absolute {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="position-relative">
  <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle"></div>
</div>
```

Related : [Bootstrap documentation - Center elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/#center-elements)